# SharedWorker in Salesforce VisualForce app issue

Tags: javascript, salesforce, visualforce, apex

I have a managed app made using visualforce and apex and not a lighting app. The app uses sharedworker in the background. The issue is that app works perfectly from the admin account and I can see a shared worker getting created for the app.

But problem comes when we install app for the other users. In the case everything works other than features using sharedworker. While debugging, I found out that for non-admin users, shared worker is not getting created itself.

In the debugging, I found out that, if I pause the cause using a breakpoint, I can see the shared worker in the debugger but can't inspect it but as soon as I resume the execution of code, the shared worker gets removed.

This is code, I am running to make the shared worker:

```
worker = new SharedWorker('/resource/worker', 'eee-salesforce');
startWorker();
```

`worker` is the JS file which has the shared worker code.

```
function startWorker() {
        worker.port.start();
        worker.port.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
            var parsedEventData = JSON.parse(event.data);
            var parsedData = parsedEventData.data;
            switch (parsedEventData.type) {
                case 'connected':
                    break;
                case 'reqUser':
                    worker.port.postMessage(['username', getLocalStorageValue("user"), getLocalStorageValue("domain")]);
                    break;
                case 'incoming':
                    createNotification(parsedData);
                    break;
                case 'incomingDesktop':
                    createDesktopNotification(parsedData);
                    break;
                case 'call':
                    break;
                case 'logout':
                    sforce.interaction.cti.disableClickToDial();
                    $("#homepage").hide();
                    $("#login").show();
                    break;
            }
        });
        window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
            worker.port.postMessage('unload');
            return null;
        });
    }
```

And in firefox, I am getting this error: 
`The resource from “https://eeesf.na50.visual.force.com/resource/worker” was blocked due to MIME type mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)`

But I checked my static packages and the mime type of this file is `application/javascript`.

I am out of ideas on how to fix this issue, if anyone experience this issue in the past or any idea how to go about fixing this issue, I will be grateful for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Had very similar use make sure to use the visual force merge syntax  to create the worker

worker = new SharedWorker('{!$Resource.Worker}', 'eee-salesforce');